# What are the skills required to work on joomla site

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I am developer myself with experience on html/css, bootstrap, javascript, jquery and nodejs. I have never worked with php till now.

Is php a essential skill when working with joomla. Can I get it working with javascript instead of php if there is any customization required?

Comment: **Knowledge** of basics.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla! development has 3 dimensions.

1. Website development with Joomla!
2. Joomla! Template Development.
3. Joomla! Extension Development.

More exactly,

1. If you just wanna **develop websites** with Joomla, you won't even need to know HTML, CSS etc.
2. For designing **Joomla! Templates** you'll need to use PHP but you don't need to be a PHP expert. You can handle it by some copy/paste jobs if you wouldn't like to go through it. Also, you need to use HTML, CSS, JS and other code derived from them (jQuery, bootstrap, nodejs etc.), but not necessarily. Depending on what functions you want to have in theme.
3. But in case of **Joomla! Extension** development, you'll need a good understanding of PHP. Also, since Joomla! uses its own-built PHP classes (FrameWork), you'll need to know about Joomla's PHP too.